# Separator insets not working

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, ios7, uikit

I have a `UITableView` in a `Storyboard` where I have configured the Separator Inset to custom (0,0) as well as for the Prototype Cell (0,0).

While I can see the separator line is now 100% the width of the table, the `UIImageView` (subclassed to AsyncImageView) is still positioned to the right by 15px.

I've tried setting it on the table view on load and when the cell is constructed from a dequeue but I'm still seeing a padding on the left. (I've queried the cell and table and the inset and frame has zero left padding).

Is there anything I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to subclass UITableViewCell and call layoutSubviews from your newly created UITableViewCell class, in the layoutSubviews method, use

```
- (void)layoutSubviews{
    [super layoutSubviews];
    self.imageView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50); // override frame of your choice
}
```

Comment: `[super layoutSubviews]` was the missing bit in my case!